# Minimum value without using aggregate functions SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables: `t1(id, ticket)` and `t2(id, value)`.

I want to select the tickets from ***t1*** which have the **smallest value** from ***t2*** without using aggregate functions(**MIN**). I have to use ANY or ALL or EXIST or IN. Value is a number.

The 2 tables are linked based on id.

Can someone help me? Thank you!!

```
SELECT ticket 
  FROM t1
 WHERE id= (SELECT id FROM t2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without using aggregate functions"? And WHY?

Comment: Also... the post is tagged MySQL as well as Oracle. Are you using both? Only one of them? NEITHER? Please edit the tags (under your post) and keep only the relevant ones.

Comment: Which one is it, Oracle or MySQL? Those are two very different animals.

Comment: and what is "Value" when you say " the smallest value from t2"

Comment: Moreover, you'd better to share some sample input and desired output as helping the question more comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions such as `DENSE_RANK()` provided the database is Oracle10g+ or MySQL8+

```
 SELECT ticket
   FROM
   (
   SELECT t1.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ID ORDER BY t2.VALUE) AS dr  
     FROM t1
     JOIN t2 
       ON t2.id = t1.ID
    )
   WHERE dr = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do :

```
select t1.tickets from t1,t2 
where t1.id-t2.id and t1.id in (select id from t2 where 
value in (select min(value) from t2));
```